# Как сумировать вывод массива в java?

Tags: java, java-8

Сразу говорю, в програмировании новичек, но нашел себе задание по созданию програмы для расчета с API интеграцией. Успешно создал вывод, которые выглядит следующим образом:

```
3600
3600
3600
3600
3600
3600
3600
3300
3600
3060
3600
3600
3600
```

Выводиться это одной переменной. Внимание вопрос. Как мне вот этот вывод сумировать, кроме как в ручную?
Была идея прочитать вывод еще раз, и как-то их засунуть по отдельности. Не знаю. Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Что значит "выводиться это одной переменной"?

Comment: System.out.println(output);

и вывод вышe из json скрипта.

Answer (score 1):

```
int value = Stream.of(output.split("\n"))
                  .mapToInt(Integer::valueOf)
                  .sum()
```

Comment: Происходит ошибка, якобы .split может быть использован только со String, при этом "output" integer

Comment: @luxor если output типа Integer, то `System.out.println(output)` никак не может вывести то, что вы привели. Показывайте весь код.